# django form does not propagate data to server side

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a template in my Django project which uses a combination of HTML and javascript. The template consists of two date and a text field. I am trying to send this across to the server side but with little success. Can someone please advise.

template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
   });
   $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
    });

   $(document).ready(
   function()
   {
        $('#myform').ajaxForm({
                    beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options)
                    {
                        var field=$('#datepicker').val();
                        if (field!=null)
                        {
                            $('#my_form').ajaxStart( function()
                            { alert('loading'); });
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    success: function(response)
                    {                            
                    }
                });
  }
);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="my_form"></p>
    <form action="" method="post" id="myform">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ myform.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

view:

```
def index(request):
    template = 'my_site/index.html'
    if request.is_ajax():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST 
        my_form = GraphForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            new = my_form.save(commit=True)
            response = { 'status':True, }
        else:
            response = {'status': str(my_form) }
        json = simplejson.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False)
        return HttpResponse(json, content_type="application/json")

    context = {'my_form':my_form}
    return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    form = GraphForm()
    return render(request,"my_site/index.html", { 'form' : form } )
```

form:

```
class GraphForm(forms.Form):
    my_form = forms.CharField(label = 'my_form',max_length=100)
    start_date = forms.DateField(required=True)
    end_date = forms.DateField(required=True)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, in both the JS and Python.

Comment: Your Form action is 
`<form action="" ...>`

Set it to 
`<form action="." ...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form should look like this

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" id="myform">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ myform.as_p }}
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="my_form"></p>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" />
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks, also how can i print out the values on the view / server side?

Comment: You should give a unique name for each textbox,
example:
    `<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" >
    <input type="text" name ="datepicker2" id="datepicker2">`

And in views.py

   `datepicker = request.POST.get('datepicker')
   datepicker2 = request.POST.get('datepicker2')`
this should work.

Comment: this looks like it works! But now I have noticed my form is invalid, any ideas why that is?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by invalid, Could you explain more?

Comment: i fixed it, now I am seeing something wrong in the view, I need to send some json back to the client side, can you help me here or do i need to create another issue?

Comment: Please create a new issue and put more details, I will try to answer.

Comment: ok here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373338/django-client-not-drawing-form-and-displaying-response

Answer (score 0):

your input fields:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="my_form"></p>
```

is out of form so when the form is submitted these are not included in that. Also if you are using django form then you have no need to define fields again. You can call datepicker on your django fields. There id's will be id_start_date and id_end_date. you can apply datepicker on that like
$( "#id_start_date" ).datepicker(); and $( "#id_date_end" ).datepicker();

Comment: I am not sure if this is clear to me, can you please provide me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Your action URL is not set. Where will the POST data go?

```
<body>
    <form action="." method="post" id="myform">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ myform.as_p }}
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="my_form"></p>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, also how can i print out the values on the view / server side?

Comment: Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form

Comment: i get key error when i type print my_form.cleaned_data['datepicker']

Comment: Why are you saying `{{ myform.as_p }}` and also creating your form in HTML? Django does that for you